# Slow xml query /odd execution plan for simple statement

Tags: sql-server, xml, performance

I have the query where I have 3 numbers inside an XML structure. When I look at the execution plan the it shows me the XML reader 3 times.

The two bottoms XML reader says they have executed 200 timer and it estimates 900 rows per execution.

My questions are

1. Why do I see multiple XML readers?
2. Is there any way to rewrite the SQL to one use one XML reader
3. Is the two bottoms once execution so many times as is says and generating 180000 rows?
4. Is this actually a problem or is this just bad estimates from the MSSQL

See the execution plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H11aOGclB

I have tried to add recompile to the query but it only makes it worse. I didn't expect it to work.

```sql
DECLARE @x xml;   SET @x='
<guids>
    <guid>1000000075</guid>
    <guid>1000000102</guid>
    <guid>1000000052</guid>
</guids>'; 

SELECT T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(10)') AS result  
FROM   @x.nodes('/guids/guid') T(c)
```

My expectations are that I only saw one XML reader in the execution plan.

Comment: Both the way you are doing it and the execution plan look fine to me.

Comment: it just seems stupid that MSSQL needs to loop the list multiple times and tries to join the content